# PHP: Can someone explain how this code works? (Fibonacci)

Tags: php, fibonacci

I promise this isn't homework. I'm just a curious novice.

How does this:

```
function f($i){return $i<2?$i:f($i-1)+f($i-2);}
```

(written by someone smart)

produce the same result as this

```
function fibonacci($n, $arr = array(0,1)){
    $arr[] = $arr[(count($arr) - 1)] + $arr[(count($arr) - 2)];
    if (count($arr) == $n) return $arr[$n - 1];
    else return fibonacci($n, $arr);
}
```

(mine)

I suppose I just don't get the syntax. Is there an if statement in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator "?" is named ternary operator. It is used like: p1?p2:p3  it says if p1 is true, then p2, else p3.

Answer (score 3):

The first function is shorthand.  Here's what it's doing

```
if($i < 2) { // $i < 2 ?
  return $i;
}
else { // :
  return f($i-1)+f($i-2);
}
```

By if it's less than two, the function doesn't have to be recalled.  If it is 2 or greater, the function is recursively called.

Answer (score 3):

There is an if statement in there.  It's called a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator).

```
condition ? if true : if false
```

If $i is less than 2 return $i, else return f($i-1) + f($i-2).  I'm assuming the recursive function calling isn't what you're having trouble understanding, but if it is there's a ton of examples of recursive fibonacci code if you google for it.

Answer (score 2):

The question mark is a conditional expression:

```
x ? a : b
```

evaluates to `a` if `x` is true, or `b` if it is false.

Answer (score 2):

```
function f($i){return $i<2?$i:f($i-1)+f($i-2);}
```

means

```
function f($i)
{
    if $(i < 2)
        return $i;
    return f($i-1) + f($i-2);
}
```

That's a direct expression of the Fibonacci equation.

The other function creates and uses a cache of generated results:  this is a significant optimization since evaluating fib(4), for example would otherwise evaluate fib(2) like 3 or 4 times, and fib(1) quite a few more.

Comment: Yes! Try both functions on F(100).